# Remove regions from module when window is closed

Tags: wpf, prism

I have prism module which I loading in separate application window.

When I closing it and opening again, getting error that some region is already registered. It is child region from one of my views. To make it more clear, I have next hierarchy:

```
   Shell 
     --RegionA
        --View
            --RegionB
            --RegionC
```

So when I try to navigate to RegionA with View, I getting error that RegionB is already registered. I cannot complain, it is really registered on previous window load and regions wasn't removed.

I tried to add event handler to Closing event of window but at this moment IRegionManager.Regions collection is empty for some reason.

So I need a way to handle window close event and clear regions.